# Default CSS / Standard Directory Set Up

Tags: best-practice, css

I am new to CiviCRM environment.

My company asked me if I could modify the website to not have so much blank space (white space) on the sides.  They want more content on the screen.

Please excuse my terminology.  I am still learning the CRM terminology via Market Research.

Where could I find the CSS to modify this portion?

Is there a standard directory set up for CiviCRM?

Is it best practice to set a new CiviCRM for each project?

Thank you in advance.

Laurie

Comment: Which CMS are you using?  Drupal/WordPress/Joomla ?  You can tweak the CSS but you may find just choosing a different theme does what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with trying the theme suggestion in the above comment, but if you do want to change css I would use "extras.css". See the hilited box on this page:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Resource+URLs

> "You can also define additional CSS styles to be applied to all or
>   specific page elements by adding CSS styles to the 'extra CSS' file:
>   css/extras.css. This file is included in the downloaded code, but is
>   empty by default."

It's difficult to answer the other questions because they're a little too general.

Comment: I don't find any file named `extra.css` in the code, neither any reference to it. Do I miss some plugin?

Comment: You need to create it in the core css directory, but this is outdated advice now. Better to use an extension and add css that way: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets